# variable won't update in ISR

Tags: assembly, interrupt, osdev

this is an ISR that gets executed whenever an IRQ1 is fired, but something weird is happening the data at memory location 0xb8100 is not updating, but IRQ1 is firing and the ISR is executing (I checked by displaying the keyboard scan codes).

```
_IRQ1_ISR :
    pusha

    mov ebx,0xb8050
    mov al,byte[0xB8100]
    add al,1
    mov byte[0xb8100],al

    mov byte[ebx],al

    ; EOI 
    mov al, 0x20 ; set bit 4 of OCW 2 
    out 0x20, al 
    
    popa

   
    iret
```

I am using the Gcc compiler and linker, with the Nasm assembler

**Edit:** this is not unique to the memory location 0xb8100, if I use any memory location, or Global Variable the issue is still the same .

Comment: You are reading `b8100` with two zeroes but writing `b81000` with 3 zeroes. Make sure you use the exact code you post.

Comment: @Jester sorry I just made a mistake when copying the code, in the original code I am not making this mistake .

Comment: Is it possible to make all the code (and command used to compile/assemble/link to make this question an [mcve]

Comment: Your ISR depends on `ds` being set.  Does any code ever change DS? Perhaps code inside the BIOS if it's interruptible?  I'd recommend setting a breakpoint on the ISR code using Bochs' built-in debugger.

Comment: @PeterCordes I fixed the issue by updating the code in a weird way, I just added `mov dx,0x60` and `in al,dx` before the EOI and it is working and the memory location is updating. what is happening and what am I missing ?

Comment: No idea.  Perhaps @MichaelPetch would have an idea of what problem that change might happen to avoid, either for good reason or by chance because of surrounding code we can't see.

Comment: @PeterCordes Without a [mcve] I don't know (Is this in real mode, 16/32 bit protected mode, long mode?), but what I can say is that if an IRQ1 fires and you do not read the keyboard code from port 0x60 and then exit the interrupt handler - you will receive no further IRQ1 (keyboard) interrupts from the keyboard controller.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Ok I get it now, so the problem wasn't with the memory location not updating, it was with the IRQ1 firing only once because I wasn't reading from port 0x60  (the code is running in protected mode)
thank you for your help